# Is there any other method in Laravel, like whereJsonContains to search inside a json column?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

the structure of json column socials is as below:

`{"1":{"type":"Facebook","url":"fb.com\/rahul"},"2":{"type":"Twitter","url":"twt.com\/rahul"}}`

and inside model the column socials is casted as `AsArrayObject::class`.

So, I want to get all the models where `"type" : "Facebook"` is present in socials column.
For that, I tried using `whereJsonContains` as follows:

```
public function index()
    {
        return Creator::whereJsonContains('socials.type','Facebook')->get();
    }
```

But this code is giving null value. Help me to get all the models where `"type" : "Facebook"` is present inside socials column.

Answer (score 0):

You should query your column using the `->` operator, not the dot notation. See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses (first paragraph).

Furthermore your query syntax doesn't match your dataset, as you're trying to access a first level property in a dataset, while your dataset is nested.